# controls inside my DockPanel do not fit to my page width as expected

Tags: c#, xaml, dockpanel

I do not manage to have my GroupBox take as much space as possible

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
            <GroupBox Header="MyTitle"  >
            </GroupBox>
 </DockPanel>
```

I thought that

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
```

would do the trick but it does not.

I also tried this way with no better results:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
                <GroupBox Header="MyTitle"  >
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
                        </DockPanel>
                </GroupBox>
     </DockPanel>
```

Concretely, with both attempts, the groupbox width = the width of "MyTitle".
I would like it to fit to the page.

EDIT:
Not sure if it makes a difference, this block is included into a grid with variable width:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="570"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>  <---------------- the dockpanel is in this column although I dropped the tags into this post            
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.58*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.42*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Is your DockPanel contained within any other layout controls?

Comment: Then in this case I think you simply forgot to set DockPanel's `Column` attached property: `<DockPanel Grid.Column="3">`.

Comment: no, I did not forget this. I just dropped it from the original post for convenience reasons (assuming that the issue does not have to do with the containing grid).

Comment: I thought that the problem might be the Grid (or maybe some other parent container) because the DockPanel stretches its content to fill all avaiable space inside its own container, not the page itself. So try to inspect carefully the logical tree of your page and see if nothing limits your DockPanel's width.